# ¿Cómo formatear el tipo de dato "Time" en CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

Lo que pasa es que en el index.ctp tengo esto:

```
<td><?= h($programacione->PrgHoraViaje->format('h:i')) ?></td>
```

Me muestra lo siguiente:

```
7:30
```

Yo quisiera que me muestre

```
7:30 **PM** ó **AM** *si fuese el caso*
```

> El campo **HoraViaje** es de tipo Time en MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El ORM de CakePHP te devuelve una instancía de [Cake\I18n\Time](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html) para cada campo de fecha o tiempo en la base de datos, por lo que podrás darle formato utilizando su API.

La función `i18nFormat()` recibe como parámetro un [IntlDateFormatter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) o un [date format string de ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details)

El código:

```
<?= $horarios->HoraViaje->i18nFormat('HH:mm a')  ?>
```

imprimirá

```
21:48 PM
```

Por cierto la función `h()` es un *wrapper* para la función de PHP `htmlspecialchars()`, es útil utilizarlo cuando es texto que necesita ser escapado, en este caso no considero que se necesite.

---

**Cabe mencionar que** `format` recibe los mismos parámetros de `i18nFormat` es correcto utilizar ambas, la diferencia es que `format` es de la clase `Date` que utiliza UTC para sus cálculos, mientras que `Time` puede recibir un TimeZone.

Otra diferencia importante es que `format` recibe un string con el formato mencionado [aquí](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), mientras que `i18nFormat` recibe el [formato ICU](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details) antes mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

acabo de utilizar este código:

```
<td><?= h($programacione->PrgHoraViaje->format('h:i A')) ?></td>
```

Y obtengo la hora, pero en formato de 12 horas:

```
7:30 AM
```

Ahora, he aquí mi duda, **¿cuál debería usar para buenas prácticas?**

Comment: Me adelanté ;) Recuerda que esta sección es solo para respuestas, si tienes alguna duda puedes dejar un comentario debajo de cualquier respuesta :D